# Есть ли какие нибудь книги по сетевым технологиям

Tags: книги, сеть, ip, tcp-ip, шлюз

Здравствуйте, пожалуйста, посоветуйте книги по сетевым технологиям. Хочу понять как делятся IP-адреса и зачем нужны маска подсети и шлюз. В этих вопросах я полный ноль и хотелось бы получить книгу где от малого к большему :)

Спасибо за понимание.